# get accumulator voting value (parameter space) in OpenCV Hough circle transform

Tags: opencv

I am novice in OpenCV. I am working on Hough circle transform. I want to get the graph or image of accumulator voting values in OpenCV (example, in MATLAB, we use H for that purpose `[H,T,R] = hough(EdgeImage);`).

Can anybody tell any method or function  and give code in opencv c++ to do so. Thanks